# how update a list value, matching another list

Tags: python, list, replace

Lets say I have a total of four lists, that look like this

```
OrderNum1 = ['110','375']
originaltime = ['12AM','5AM']

OrderNum2 = ['110','215']
newtime = ['2AM', '3AM']
```

Is there a way to replace the originaltime values only when a value from ordernum1 and ordernum2 match?

The goal is to replace 12AM with 2AM in this case because index 0 of ordernum1 and ordernum2 are both '110' so the output would look like

```
print(originaltime)
2AM, 5AM
```

Comment: simple if condition will do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
OrderNum1 = ['110','375']
originaltime = ['12AM','5AM']

OrderNum2 = ['110','215']
newtime = ['2AM', '3AM']

for i in range(len(OrderNum1)):
    if OrderNum1[i] == OrderNum2[i]:
        originaltime[i] = newtime[i]

print(originaltime)
```

Output:

```
['2AM', '5AM']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `zip()` and `enumerate()`:

```
OrderNum1 = ['110','375']
originaltime = ['12AM','5AM']

OrderNum2 = ['110','215']
newtime = ['2AM', '3AM']

for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(OrderNum1,OrderNum2)):
    if a == b:
        originaltime[i] = newtime[i]
```